# error starting pm2 in cluster mode in windows

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, pm2

I am getting an error while starting pm2 in cluster mode.
I ran this command -

`pm2 start <filename> -i 4`

Only one instance gets created. 
I am using Windows 7, Node 0.12.0 and pm2 0.14.0

This is my error log

> 2015-06-18 10:52:04: [PM2][WORKER] Started with refreshing interval:
>   30000 2015-06-18 10:52:04: [[[[ PM2/God daemon launched ]]]]
>   2015-06-18 10:52:04: BUS system [READY] on port \.\pipe\pub.sock
>   2015-06-18 10:52:04: RPC interface [READY] on port \.\pipe\rpc.sock
>   2015-06-18 10:52:04: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for
>   app name:server id:0 2015-06-18 10:52:04: App name:server id:0 online
>   2015-06-18 10:52:04: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for
>   app name:server id:1 2015-06-18 10:52:04: Trace: { [Error: spawn
>   EBADF] code: 'EBADF', errno: 'EBADF', syscall: 'spawn' }
>       at Object.God.logAndGenerateError (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God\Methods.js:30:15)
>       at Object.nodeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God\ClusterMode.js:52:11)
>       at Object.executeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:145:9)
>       at ex (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:361:18)
>       at C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:365:16
>       at Worker.cluOnline (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:188:17)
>       at Worker.g (events.js:199:16)
>       at Worker.emit (events.js:104:17)
>       at online (cluster.js:449:12)
>       at Worker.onmessage (cluster.js:436:7) 2015-06-18 10:52:04: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:server id:2
>   2015-06-18 10:52:05: Trace: { [Error: spawn EBADF] code: 'EBADF',
>   errno: 'EBADF', syscall: 'spawn' }
>       at Object.God.logAndGenerateError (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God\Methods.js:30:15)
>       at Object.nodeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God\ClusterMode.js:52:11)
>       at Object.executeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:145:9)
>       at ex (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:361:18)
>       at C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:362:25
>       at nodeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:146:29)
>       at Object.nodeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God\ClusterMode.js:53:14)
>       at Object.executeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:145:9)
>       at ex (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:361:18)
>       at C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:365:16
>   2015-06-18 10:52:05: Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for
>   app name:server id:3 2015-06-18 10:52:05: Trace: { [Error: spawn
>   EBADF] code: 'EBADF', errno: 'EBADF', syscall: 'spawn' }
>       at Object.God.logAndGenerateError (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God\Methods.js:30:15)
>       at Object.nodeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God\ClusterMode.js:52:11)
>       at Object.executeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:145:9)
>       at ex (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:361:18)
>       at C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:362:25
>       at nodeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:146:29)
>       at Object.nodeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God\ClusterMode.js:53:14)
>       at Object.executeApp (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:145:9)
>       at ex (C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:361:18)
>       at C:\Users\pbaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\God.js:362:25

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem today too.

If I run "pm2 logs" before any other pm2 operation, and then start applications in cluster mode ("pm2 start app.js -i 4"), everything looks fine. It seems pm2 need some time for initialization. I have no idea about the real reason.

Looking forward for better solution too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple: restart the pc or server.

Answer (score -3):

On Windows, don't use clusters:

```
pm2 start "filename.js"
```